# Migrating a joomla install - getting blank page with no errors

Tags: php, apache, joomla

Apache server, migrating from IIS - I have error reporting on, I have access to the server logs, neither are reporting any errors but the pages still come up blank both at

```
http://204.12.74.110/index.php
http://204.12.74.110/administrator/index.php
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your PHP version? Check if all the resources are the same in the new server.

for Joomla 2.5.x, 1.7.x and 1.6.x

```
Software         Recommended       Minimum  
PHP              5.3 +             5.2.4 +  
MySQL            5.0.4 +           5.0.4 + 
Microsoft IIS    7                 7
```

and for Joomla 3.x you can check this link: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you set error reporting to maximum in your joomla configuration? If you can't access the backend trough the browser, change the configuration.php file by hand and set the following variable to maximum

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
```

Sometimes white pages are caused by file permission problems. Try to add the following code to the top of your index.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

To make sure the file is called add an

```
echo 'hello';die;
```

to your index.php file as well. I assume PHP is correctly configured with Apache?